# Some paster command not working in ckan 2.7.3

Tags: centos7, ckan, paster

Trying to use the info in:

http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.4.3/authorization.html

to create users and assign roles to specifics package and the command **right** not working.

For instance:

```
paster --plugin=ckan rights -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini list
```

I get error:

```
Command 'rights' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
Known commands:
  celeryd           Celery daemon [DEPRECATED]
  check-po-files    Check po files for common mistakes
  color             Create or remove a color scheme.
  config-tool       Tool for editing options in a CKAN config file
  create            Create the file layout for a Python distribution
  create-test-data  Create test data in the database.
  datapusher        Perform commands in the datapusher
  dataset           Manage datasets
  datastore         Perform commands to set up the datastore
  db                Perform various tasks on the database.
  exe               Run #! executable files
  front-end-build   Creates and minifies css and JavaScript files
  help              Display help
  jobs              Manage background jobs
  less              Compile all root less documents into their CSS counterparts
  make-config       Install a package and create a fresh config file/directory
  minify            Create minified versions of the given Javascript and CSS files.
  notify            Send out modification notifications.
  plugin-info       Provide info on installed plugins.
  points            Show information about entry points
  post              Run a request for the described application
  profile           Code speed profiler
  ratings           Manage the ratings stored in the db
  rdf-export        Export active datasets as RDF
  request           Run a request for the described application
  search-index      Creates a search index for all datasets
  serve             Serve the described application
  setup-app         Setup an application, given a config file
  sysadmin          Gives sysadmin rights to a named user
  tracking          Update tracking statistics
  trans             Translation helper functions
  user              Manage users
  views             Manage resource views.
```

but if I create a user like this:

```
paster sysadmin add seanh -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
```

works ok, so I don't think the problem was in my enviroment.

**Note:**

```
Centos 7.4
ckan 2.7.3
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Rights' was deprecated in the migration to CKAN 2.X, and the paster command removed.

From CKAN 2.0, permissions are organization by organization and by group. It's a simplification, catering for what is considered the most common use case.

However if you need to control user permissions on a single dataset (rather than all the datasets in an org/group together) then that dataset needs to be on its own in a org or group. Or you can customize the auth system using IAuthFunctions.

Comment: Thanks. I need permissions by organization. For instance an editor user to one organization. I can't find doc for do that.

Comment: Docs: http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/authorization.html Or maybe it's best you ask a fresh SO question